# Cannot get data in data row

Tags: c#, dataset

Here is my main test case method, the error occur at line

> target.DeletePHIParmYield(rowToDelete);

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void DeletePHIParmYieldTest()
    {
        CommonPHIEditorBL_Accessor target = new CommonPHIEditorBL_Accessor();
        target.mCommonPHIEditorDS = new CommonPHIEditorDS();
        PHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinition rowToDelete = new PHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinition();
        //Test Case 1
        AddPHIYieldInfo(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm, 1, 12, 123, 1234, 2001);
        rowToDelete.ItemID = "2001";
        rowToDelete.MetricKeyID = "12";
        rowToDelete.ProjectName = "Test";
        rowToDelete.ProjectType = "MOR";
        rowToDelete.Status = "MOR";
        rowToDelete.SubObject = "CFA";
        rowToDelete.Factory = "VF";
        rowToDelete.ParameterName = "BI%";
        target.DeletePHIParmYield(rowToDelete); //error inside here
        //Assert.AreEqual(0, target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm.Rows.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm.Rows.Count);

    }
```

Go inside the function of DeletePHIParmYield(rowToDelete):

```
    public void DeletePHIParmYield(PHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinition rowToDelete)
        {
            int id;

            CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow sourceRow = GetPHIRow(rowToDelete);
            if (sourceRow == null)
                throw new Exception("Row cannot be located!");

            if (!sourceRow.IsMetricModelInputIDNull())
                id = sourceRow.MetricModelInputID; 
            else
                id = sourceRow.InputID;
DeletePHIYieldParmDataAndAcceptChanges(sourceRow);
            sourceRow.Delete();

 if (id < 0 && sourceRow.RowState != DataRowState.Detached) //this record is not in DB. No need to call to DB
                sourceRow.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

Go inner to CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow sourceRow=GetPHIRow(rowToDelete);

```
public CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow GetPHIRow(PHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinition newRowObj)
    {
        CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow row = null;

        string filter = ConstructFilterUsingPHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinitionObject(newRowObj);

        CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow[] existingRow
            = (CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow[])MCommonPhiEditorDs.PHIYieldParm.Select(filter, string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);



        //var existingRow = from filter in MCommonPhiEditorDs.PHIYieldParm
        //                  where filter.MetricTypeName.StartsWith("BI")
        //                  select existingRow;
        //row = existingRow.FirstOrdefault();



        if (existingRow != null && existingRow.Length == 1)
            row = existingRow[0];

        return row;
    }
```

The data in Filter:(I do change to "LIKE" instead of "=" to try)

> MetricTypeName = 'BI%' AND Factory = 'VF' AND Status = 'MOR' AND ProjectName = 'Test' AND ProjectType = 'MOR' AND SubObjectName = 'CFA' AND ItemID = '2001' AND MetricKeyID = '12' AND MetricModelInputID IS NULL

PHIYieldParmData Table contain the column of :(with no data, I do manually put in data to try)

```
DataID, MetricModelInputID, MetricID, InputID, ItemID, DateKey, Value, HrzDisplay, HorizonID, MetricModelID, AggregateItemChar
```

I could not get the data when going through the line

> row = existingRow[0];

it cannot run through the above line, but straight away jump to this. There is because of the if else condition. However, there is a problem in my **existingRow**, I could not load data into that

```
return row;
```

My **string** contain a list of data, while **existingRow** is empty

Full Code:

```
public CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow GetPHIRow(PHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinition newRowObj)
{
    CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow row = null;

    string filter = ConstructFilterUsingPHIEditorUniquePHIRowDefinitionObject(newRowObj);

    CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow[] existingRow
        = (CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow[])MCommonPhiEditorDs.PHIYieldParm.Select(filter, string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

    if (existingRow != null && existingRow.Length == 1)          
        row = existingRow[0];

    return row;
}
```

Comment: _"because of the if else condition"_ which else? Have you used the debugger, what is the value of `filter`? In general i would prefer Linq-To-DataSet.

Comment: yes, because of the if-else, but I suppose to meet the if condition, the "existingRow" should not be null, but the existingRow return me null. The Value inside filter is "MetricTypeName = 'BI%' AND Factory = 'VF' AND Status = 'MOR' AND ProjectName = 'Test' AND ProjectType = 'MOR' AND SubObjectName = 'CFA' AND ItemID = '2001' AND MetricKeyID = '1' AND MetricModelInputID IS NULL"

Comment: the problem occur here "CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow[] existingRow
        = (CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow[])MCommonPhiEditorDs.PHIYieldParm.Select(filter, string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);", why do the "existingRow" return me nothing?

Comment: there is a data inside table "PHIYieldParm" too

Comment: Do you want to use `MetricTypeName LIKE 'BI%'` instead? If you use `=` instead of `LIKE` you are searching for the exaxt string not a sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

You commented that this is your filter for `DataTable.Select`:

```
MetricTypeName = 'BI%' AND 
Factory = 'VF' AND 
Status = 'MOR' AND 
ProjectName = 'Test' AND 
ProjectType = 'MOR' AND 
SubObjectName = 'CFA' AND 
ItemID = '2001' AND 
MetricKeyID = '1' AND 
MetricModelInputID IS NULL
```

Do you want to use `MetricTypeName LIKE 'BI%'` instead? If you use `=` instead of `LIKE` you are searching for the exaxt string not a sub-string.

So:

```
MetricTypeName LIKE 'BI%' AND 
// ....
```

But i prefer Linq-To-DataSet:

```
var rows = from phiRow in MCommonPhiEditorDs.PHIYieldParm
           where phiRow.MetricTypeName.StartsWith("BI")
            &&   phiRow.Factory == "VF"
           // ....
           select phiRow;
CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmRow row = rows.FirstOrdefault();
```

Comment: I do change my value from "=" to "LIKE", but I still fail to get the data into existingRow, my existingRow return me null

Comment: I have changed and use the Linq-To-DataSet as suggested above, but still fail to get the data for existing row...where do I did wrong? I am first time to do this

Comment: It's really difficult to help without having sample data. What row(s) do you expect, show a little sample `DataTable` in your question.

Comment: @nodisplay: i don't know if that's the issue but you are filtering by `MetricTypeName = 'BI%'` and the sample row contains only a `ParameterName` which value is `'BI%`.